# A definition related to pseudoprimes and the Dedekind psi function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences, divisors-multiples, arithmetic-functions

In this post we consider that $\psi(k)$ denotes the Dedekind psi function. Wikipedia has an artcle dedicated to this arithmetic function [*Dedekind psi function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) defined for a positive integers $m>1$ as

$$\psi(m)=m\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\tag{1}$$
with the definition $\psi(1)=1.$

**Definition.** Inspired in the book [1] (pages 144-146), I define the *Luca-Somer numbers* as the positive integers $n\geq 1$ such that $n\mid a^{\psi(n)}-b^{\psi(n)}$ whenever $(a\cdot b,n)=1$.

**Claim.** *It is inmeditate to check that Rotkewicz numbers of the form $n=pq$ that got Rotkiewiccz in his works about a similar question and that present the authors, are also Luca-somer numbers*.

An example is $n=2\cdot 3$. On the other hand I've considered that it is easy the proof, in a same way that did the authors, to prove a Lemma that asserts for our definition.

**Lemma.** *A positive integer* $n\geq 1$ *is a Luca-Somer number if an only if* $c^{\psi(n)}\equiv 1\text{ mod }n$, *whenever the integer* $c\geq 1$ *satisfies* $(c,n)=1$.

And from here I wondered about more examples of families (maybe exploting as did the authors some alternative characterization of Lucas-Somer numbers, as they computed by using their Lemma 12.31).

> **Question.** I would like to know if you can provide reasonings to get more families of Luca-Somer numbers (maybe a different characterization of our Definition is required). **Many thanks.**

The authors compute such families of Rotkiewicz numbers as Theorem 12.32, 12.33 and 12.34 exploiting their characterization of Rotkiewicz numbersProposition 12.32.

### References:

[1] Michael Křižek, Florian Luca and Lawrence Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat Numbers*, CMS Books in Mathematics, Canadian Mathematical Society, Springer-Verlag (2001).

Comment: I would like to dedicate the post to these professors who wrote the book, Michal, Florian and Lawrence.

Comment: The exponent of $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}^\times$ is the lcm of the $(p-1)p^{k-1}$ where $p^k\| n$ (unless $p=2,k\ge 3$ in which case it is $2^{k-2}$) and you want it to divide $\psi(n)$.

Comment: It would be so much better, 142929, if you would include the definitions of Dedekind psi and of Rotkiewicz numbers in the body of your post.

Comment: Professor @GerryMyerson **the definition of Rotkiewicz numbers** is the similar relation that I refer in my definition, but with a divisor function, see [1] or [2] Florian Luca and Lawrence Sommer, *A remark on a question of Rotkiewicz*, Colloq. Math. (submitted 2000), pages 1-5. Many thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I've added such $n$ to the OEIS as sequence [A353868](https://oeis.org/A353868).

Comment: Many thanks, please add your name as author of the entry of the OEIS sequence, I call/define this sequence as *Luca-Somer numbers* but feel free to edit as you consider. Many thanks for your attention and help adding excellent answers @MaxAlekseyev